Why does CharsetEncoder.maxBytesPerChar() return a float?
This does not make sense to me why method CharsetEncoder.maxBytesPerChar() returns a float and not an integer, since this is a maximum.
Do encoding mechanisms that use partial bytes exist?
Can I assume the returned float can always be casted to an integer with no data loss?

Perhaps to be consistent with averageBytesPerChar()

BASE64 uses partial bytes (but I would not define an charset encoder). I assume they were ready for weird encodings.

These are often unanswerable because the question boils down to: "What was this ONE person who made this API thinking 15 years ago?" - unless that one person reads this and is around, how can anybody answer? As far as guesstimates go: To be consistent with averageBytesPerChar. It's not a crucial issue; the rule is: Given that I encode X chars, the total bytes I end up needing must never be higher than ROUND_UP(X*getMaxBytesPerChar()). It doesn't actually require an int for that to be an applicable formula.

And as a second reason, imagine I have some bizarro encoding that encodes every char as 12 bits, compressing as we go (so 2 chars fit in 3 bytes). Then the answer is a simple 1.5F. Float rounding will cause some minor havoc here, but 1.5F is actually a perfect float (exactly representable, unlike, say, 1.1F which doesn't exist).

maybe related to how the Encoder/Decoder are implemented, that is, kind of generic (not Generics of Java) by a template - see Charset-X-Coder.java.template -- The method is (apparently, not checked) given by public final float max$ItypesPerOtype$() {   return max$ItypesPerOtype$;  }

Well the superficial answer is that maxBytesPerChar() returns a float simply because both protected constructors for CharsetEncoder include a float maxBytesPerChar parameter. That obviously doesn't resolve your underlying concern, but your question would still be better framed by rewording to ask why those CharsetEncoder constructors require a float argument rather than asking about the method CharsetEncoder.maxBytesPerChar().

The method returns a float because the max. number of bytes/character could actually be fractional depending on the method of encoding.
If future encodings had fractional bytes/character instead of say, UTF-8's 1-4 bytes/character, you may have been thankful.
So to answer your question, yes I would assume. As long as you know the encoding scheme and whether or not fractional bytes are being toyed with, you can make the decision yourself.
